# Checking In Luggage During Intermediate Leg

Tags: luggage, united-airlines

I am traveling to SFO using LHR-EWR-SFO flight. The layover at EWR is ~10 hours.

I wanted to buy something (a little bulky) in New York for the friend I am visiting in SFO and wanted to check this piece in. Since I have to re-check the rest of my luggage once I enter US any way, could I *add* a piece of baggage too?

Comment: You won't be able to _add_ it during the recheck, because the recheck happens when you arrive into EWR - pretty much straight away.  However you most likely should be able to check in another bag when you return to the airport, as long as you're within your checked in luggage allowance or you pay for the extra bag.  Do check with the airline though.

Answer (score 1):

I was starting to wonder whether you could get back to the drop off or is it behind security but then I realized something: you won't be able to add it during the recheck because last I've done this (although not at EWR but I suspect it's the same) it was not like a full service station complete with baggage tag printers just a simple drop off. Thinking more, it is one drop off for every airline so there's really no way to get your thing into the airline system. That would require a replication of the check-in floor. As your luggage is tagged to the end already, you can simply drop it off here but untagged baggage just can't happen.

As for adding more luggage I can't imagine why the airline wouldn't accept it if you pay the extra luggage fee. My train of thought is -- if you'd need to gate check something then you can so I am sure they'll be happy with not messing with a gate check.