# Extra luggage drop-off in Dubai by Emirates during layover

Tags: regulations, layovers, emirates

When I purchase flight ticket in same agency and with Emirates/code share (for example JFK-DXB-PVG) and clear customs & immigration during the layover, can I drop off extra luggage in Dubai to final destination (DXB- PVG), if:

1. I have not dropped off luggage before?
2. My free luggage allowance (Number & Weight) has not used up?
3. I have already used all free luggage allowance and wish to purchase extra luggage allowance in layover cities counter?

PS: Please not that a possible duplicate of [Checking In Luggage During Intermediate Leg](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/46330/checking-in-luggage-during-intermediate-leg) is talking about United, not Emirates.

Comment: Where will this mystery piece of extra luggage be coming from? And will you be entering Dubai (clearing customs+immigration) during the layover?

Comment: My question is asked before you day duplicate question @flimzy

Comment: @Him: I realize that. But that doesn't really matter.

Comment: @Flimzy But you wake up a bad question and do something meaningless

Comment: @Him: No, I "woke up" a bad question to consolidate it, and the other several semi-duplicates, into a single, authoritative answer, as per [this meta post](http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/q/3461/444).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ask the staff of Emirates in Dubai and they say ok